# DevApp ionic devapp=true could not be loaded because ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-devapp

i connected my phone to the same wifi network as my laptop . When i run ionic serve in my laptop i am able to see the app in my phone using ionic DevApp , but when i click on i am getting error as
devapp=true could not be loaded because ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE.

Comment: Can you manually open the IP address that is shown in `ionic serve` in the browser of your mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the firewall solved that error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling firewall, just allow Node.js access through firewall.